# Advanced coloured lines following robot

Tags: robotic

I am trying to build a coloured lines following robot, and I would like to know what kind of sensors do I use for my robot to differentiate and detect several different coloured lines?

Comment: What hardware/software are you using (NXT, EV3, etc..)?

Comment: [ObGrammarJoke] Why does the bot have to be coloured?

Comment: @gev Ba-dum Tish!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the EV3 Sensors you should use the EV3 Color Sensor which can detect 8 colors (colorless, black, blue, green, yellow, red, white and brown). If you are using the NXT I would recommend the HiTechnic Color Sensor or [HiTechnic Color Sensor V2](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=nco1038)... I hope I could help.